# Multiple instances of app in htop

Tags: process, x11, htop, qt

Why does `htop` show two instances of my GUI app `TradeClient`?

[image]

while I started only one instance?

System: Ubuntu 22.04 VPS with X11 (I connect with VNC)

What is its CPU usage?

**EDIT1**

```
htop -t
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

without gdb:

[image]

Comment: Try htop -t. My guess is that your app is starting a helper thread of some kind. The -t will show which is the parent.

Comment: @HackSaw There are multiple threads, see EDIT1

Comment: It's running under gdb? What's it look like when it's not running in a debugger?

Comment: @HackSaw yes, see EDIT2

Comment: @HackSaw I am not sure how threads work on Linux, but on Windows a process with multiple threads has a single PID and is displayed in Task Manager in a single line, but `htop` shows two different PIDs in two separate lines.

Comment: Yeah, the thing that htop is telling us is that the first instance is the parent of the second instance. That is to say, the parent forked a new process for whatever reason. The thing I'm not sure about is the involvement of gdb, which is running those instances.

Comment: It is to be noted, though, that apps forking themselves for a variety of reasons is pretty common. In Linux the difference between a thread and a process is whether it shares memory with the parent. Processes have their own memory space.

Comment: Is this the email client from sourceforge? It appears to fork a bunch of processes to watch various email providers for new messages.

Comment: @HackSaw no, it is not the email client.

Comment: Ah, well, there's an ancient email client called that, FWIW. Anyway, on macOS and Linux, threads get process IDs, which probably lets you attach to them with debuggers, and signal them, among other things. It wouldn't surprise me if your GUI library created the thread.

Comment: @HackSaw my GUI library is QT/QML built with X11, see https://developernote.com/2023/08/building-qt6-5-2-for-x11-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: So, this is code you've written? Does it use a library to act like a server? With the number of threads you have, it looks like a server opening a handful of listeners.

Comment: @HackSaw yes, I wrote this app using QT6.5.2, but it is not a server, but a client that does HTTP queries.

Comment: It could be a client opening a number of threads to asynchronously get the data you are looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a qt tag of some sort to this so that an expert chimes in. I last wrote Qt code in the early 2000s.